# What is the appropriate way to manage and name forms in a solution?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner to Visual Studio 2015 and C# and am looking for some general advice I could not not find anywhere else, so please bear with me.

Let's say I create a new Windows Forms Application, in the Solution Explorer I can already see `Form1.cs` has been added to the tree, and child to this is `Form1.Designer.cs` and `Form1`.

Now I want to add another form by right clicking `WindowsFormApplication1` and `Add` > `New Item...`

The Solution Explorer now looks something like this:

[image]

---

For my first C# project I am recreating Notepad which should not be overly difficult, this will allow me to familiarize myself with the language and syntax etc.

I have added a second form to my project which will be the `Go To` line number form, shown from the Edit menu in Notepad.

Suppose I want to give `Form1` and `Form2` more meaningful names what is the correct way to do this?

From the properties inspector I named `Form1` as `frmMain` and `Form2` as `frmGoTo` but I noticed in the Solution Explorer the parent names are still `Form1.cs` and `Form2.cs`:

[image]

So I right clicked each parent node and renamed them too like so:

[image]

---

My question now is was this the right or wrong approach? I feel like I am going to have naming conflicts maybe.

To test I tried showing the `frmGoTo` form like so:

```
Form frmGoTo = new frmGoTo();
frmGoTo.ShowDialog();
```

I think I did this right, the `frmGoTo` does show correctly but as I say I have my doubts regarding the way I renamed the forms from both the property inspector and Solution Explorer.

Was there anything wrong with what I did above, should I have used separate naming conventions for the property inspector form name and the solution explorer name etc? Will I run into any problems naming the forms like I did above?

I suppose I am looking for some clarity as to how best to rename forms within a solution?

Comment: Normally you would name them as you make them - however, you have achieved what you needed to do

Comment: Though I can't answer for all the questions, the frmMain and frmGoto reminds me the old VB days where we used to prefix the type like txtName, btnEnable. These are not advised in modern programming languages

Comment: Yes, if you do a Rename operation VS is smart enough to do the refactoring in all the places that reference the class.

Comment: When you add a new item there is a text box at the bottom where you can change the default to the name you want.

Comment: What you did was correct.

Comment: @Thangadurai I guess I brought that habit from Delphi. I should look for a better guide on naming conventions etc but some articles are conflicting with information and I would rather adapt to modern standards than bring along old habits :)

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah I noticed this but in my haste I had already added my forms and when it came to coding I realized that `Form1` and `Form2` are not very meaningful names.

Comment: Ive always found that forms always are worth naming.. any text fields you need to get data from, buttons you're expecting to click, items you're going to update need proper names.. however, labels? if you arent changing them.. while its good practice, its like naming your socks.. it doesnt make a big difference until you start wanting to change them in which case label43 is a bit bad especially if you didnt make them in order

Comment: @Thangadurai could you perhaps give some brief examples of how forms, and buttons could be named differently? There are quite a few conflicting articles out there so if there is a definitive or widely used one that would be most helpful to me thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you did was not wrong, but there is an easier solution build into Visual Studio solution explorer. Right click on item and select rename:

[image]

Visual Studio will then ask if you want it to perform project-wide rename for the classname of the form:

[image]

By answering yes, everything should be in order.

Comment: Great, so from now if I rename using this method I shouldn't have to worry about messing up the solution or getting names mixed up etc? This gives me more reassurance rather than blindly changing things and hoping for the best.

Comment: @Craig - Generally speaking, it should be fine but I always use source control and perform a commit just before making changes that I suspect could break the solution and cause some headache. That way I can just go back to the commited version if something went wrong :). I know you're new to VS but I recommend spending a couple of hours understanding source control (such as Git). Also, +1 for Esko's answer :D

Comment: Yes, I recommend this approach. Though remember that the file-name does not have to reflect the class name inside that file. You can have file myClass.cs which has ***class person*** etc. It's not common, but may be justifiable in some situations.